# How to print 0.00009 and lower number

Tags: php

Trying to echo 0.00009 number gives me 9.0E-5 tryed to do

`echo number_format($number);`

it echoes 0, maybe someone could explain me how to print my number and even lower ones.

Comment: Have a look at this demo: https://eval.in/75660

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this...

```
number_format($number, 5, '.', '');
```

That should give you the number to 5 decimal places, using . for the decimal (English format).

**Reference**:   http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: but it still prints 0